# Django: Deleting multiple objects with a view that requires a object pk?

Tags: python, django

Hey I got this Code to remove my keys:

```py
class AKeysRemove(DeleteView, ProgramContextMixin):
    model = AKeys
    template_name = 'administration/keys/remove.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AKeysRemove, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('akeys_index', args=[self.get_program_id()])

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the query parameters from the request
        is_active = request.GET.get('is_active')
        category = request.GET.get('category')

        # Build a Q object to filter AccessKeys by is_active and category
        q_filter = Q()
        if is_active is not None:
            q_filter &= Q(is_active=is_active)
        if category is not None:
            q_filter &= Q(category=category)

        # Check if there are any filters
        has_filters = is_active is not None or category is not None

        # Delete the AKeys that match the filter, or just the one AKey
        if has_filters:
            queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(q_filter)
            deleted_count, _ = queryset.delete()
            if deleted_count == 1:
                messages.success(request, f"One AKey deleted.")
            else:
                messages.success(request, f"{deleted_count} AKeys deleted.")
        else:
            obj = self.get_object()
            obj.delete()
            messages.success(request, f"AKey {obj} deleted.")

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

My url looks like this:

```py
re_path(r'^p/(?P<p_id>[0-9]+)/keys/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/?$', AKeysRemove.as_view(), name='akeys_delete'),
```

Deleting one Single Key works fine, but I build myself a filter to delete Keys from a certain category or if they're active or not (`is_active`)

```html
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'akeys_delete' p.id %}" id="delete-akeys-form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="category-filter">Category:</label>
                                            <select name="category" id="category-filter" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">All</option>
                                                {% for category in acategories %}
                                                    <option value="{{ category.name }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="active-filter">Status:</label>
                                            <select name="is_active" id="active-filter" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">All</option>
                                                <option value="true">Active</option>
                                                <option value="false">Inactive</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The problem now is that when I open my site I get the obvious error:

`Reverse for 'akeys_delete' with arguments '(3,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/p/(?P<p_id>[0-9]+)/keys/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/?$']`

Which I understand, since its missing the key.pk, I just can't really figure out how I could re-write my code to accept both single objects to delete and multiple?

I'm thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to support multiple functionality with same view. In that case, why not write two urls pointing to the same view, like this:

```
re_path(r'^p/(?P<p_id>[0-9]+)/keys/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/?$', AKeysRemove.as_view(), name='akeys_delete'),
re_path(r'^p/(?P<p_id>[0-9]+)/keys/delete/?$', AKeysRemove.as_view(), name='akeys_multi_delete'),
```

And update the url in template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'akeys_multi_delete' p.id %}" id="delete-akeys-form">
```